http server for viewing a local git repo in browser with github/gitlab styling
is there any tool or method to start a http server for local git repo, then i can browser the code or other content in browser with github or gitlab styles?
(for a quick glance/lightweight styling of code, without open the github/gitlab webside when sometimes without net access)
i have tried local git code browser, but the solutions are ages ago and no code style rendering.

You may be better off asking the question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ given it sounds like you want an out of the box solution. Is there a reason it has to be exposed in the browser ? - there are plenty of GUI tools for git available both free and commercial.

thanks for comment, my case is that sometimes i have to review repo code on the PCs without internet connection, but i still wish to view these repos with a better/quick looks, which i found maybe httpserver in github/gitlab styling is helpful.
